# How find out number of values that one field has in a Mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in Mongodb called "Data", one of the fields in this collection might has multiple values. I would like to know how many values this field can get at the most (maximum number of values that this field can get).
Below is the query that I run:

```
db.Data.find({"outcome": {$exists: 1, $ne: null} }, {"outcome":1})
```

Here is the result:

```
{ 
    "_id" :1, 
    "outcome" : [
        "3-VD"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : 2, 
    "outcome" : [
        "3-VD", 
        "Left main"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : 3, 
    "outcome" : [
        "1-VD",
        "2-VD",
        "3-VD",
    ]
}
```

I know that with below aggregation query I get number of outcome that each document has, but I want to know what is the maximum number of outcomes in this collection!!!

`db.Data.aggregate({$project: { count: { $size:"$outcome" }}})`

Comment: @NeilLunn I had seen the similar question that you refereed to but my question is something else. Updated my question at the end!

Comment: `db.Data.aggregate([{ "$group": { "_id": null,  "maxcount": { "$max": { "$size": "$outcome"  }} }}])`. You [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) instead and pass the values from `$size` to [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/). If you already saw the answer then you should have mentioned it in your question. You did not.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for your quick and informative reply. I will definitely mention in my next question If I had seen a similar question! :)